# C3.js "Uncaught Error: Source data is missing a component at (1,844)!"

Tags: javascript, node.js, plot, electron, c3.js

I am using C3.js and Electron (Atom Shell) to make a desktop application for data visualization. I am having trouble to feed my data into C3. I have a DataArray that contains all the coordinates: DataAray = [ [x1,y1] , [x2,y2] , [x3,y3],...].
I use the following code to break it into an xData array and a yData array:

```
xData = [];
yData=[];
xData.push('data1_x');
yData.push('data1');
for (var i = 0; i < DataArray.length ; i++){
         xData.push (DataArray[i][0]);
         yData.push (DataArray[i][1]);
                }
var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart',
            data: {
                xs: {
                    data1: 'data1_x',

                },
              columns: [
                        x,
                        y
                          ],
                type: 'scatter'
                        }
                    });
```

but when I run the application, I get this error: 
**"Uncaught Error: Source data is missing a component at (1,844)!", source: PATH/To/c3-0.4.10/c3.min.js (2)**

and the graph is not plotted at all. If I change the for loop to

```
for (var i = 0; i < 843 ; i++)
```

however, it does plot the graph. 
I was using Plotly before, and I used to run the exact same code to prepare the data for Plotly, and it worked just fine. What is the problem here? Also, is there a way to ask C3 to ignore errors in the data? For example, if there is a null at one of the points, is there a way for C3 to plot the graph anyways?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a way to configure C3 to ignore null or undefined values.  Try ignoring the null/undefined values so that C3 can plot the graph.

```
for (var i = 0; i < DataArray.length ; i++) {
     // if the value is not undefined or null, push to array
     if (DataArray[i][0] !== undefined && DataArray[i][0] !== null) {
         xData.push (DataArray[i][0]);
     } else {
         // push 0 to signify no data
         xData.push(0);
     }
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C3 will ignore null values. But you will get this error when a value is undefined. The answer from TonalLynx will work. Or you could change undefined values to null.

```
for (var i = 0; i < DataArray.length ; i++) {
 // if the value is undefined, push null to array
 if (DataArray[i][0] === undefined) {
     xData.push (null);
 } else {
     xData.push (DataArray[i][0]);
 }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

c3 has an internal function that can help do that

```
c3_chart_internal_fn.convertColumnsToData = function (columns) {
    var new_rows = [], i, j, key;
    for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        key = columns[i][0];
        for (j = 1; j < columns[i].length; j++) {
            if (isUndefined(new_rows[j - 1])) {
                new_rows[j - 1] = {};
            }
            if (isUndefined(columns[i][j])) {
                throw new Error("Source data is missing a component at (" + i + "," + j + ")!");
            }
            new_rows[j - 1][key] = columns[i][j];
        }
    }
    return new_rows;
};
```